# GoLang Firestore slow batch write

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Golang with Firestore to read/write/update information by batch writes.
My code is the following:

```
t0 := time.Now()
    iter := client.Collection("subs").Where("some key", "==", lookup).Limit(499).Documents(ctx)
    defer iter.Stop()
    batch := client.Batch()
    i := 0
    for {
        sub, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        i++
        sfRef := client.Collection("subs").Doc(sub.Ref.ID)
        batch.Set(sfRef, map[string]interface{}{
            "some key": update_value,
        }, firestore.MergeAll)
    }
    commit, err := batch.Commit(ctx)
```

This batch update tooks about 1/2 sec, which is not appropriate if we need to update 500 000 entries.
I am wondering if this 1/2 sec is normal response time for Firestore and how I can optimise this query?

Answer (score 1):

One optimization, if you need to update all documents that match your query, independently of any value in it, is to ask firestore no fields at all:

```
iter := client.Collection("subs").Select().Where("some key", "==", lookup).Limit(499).Documents(ctx)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore?tab=doc#Query.Select

If your collection has documents containing sequential values in an indexed field, than it's normal, but above optimization still apply:

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain
>   sequential values in an indexed field:    500 per second

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions